# How to send output of cgi file to html file

Tags: html, bash, raspberry-pi, cgi

I am hosting a web server on a raspberry pi 4B. It has no desktop lite os. I connected 3 LEDs to the Raspberry pi GPIOs and am controlling them on website from my laptop. I can turn it off and on with buttons but I am having problem with displaying LED current status on the website. I tested it on shell and it outputs correctly.

How can I send the output of my cgi file to the index.html?

I tried to put the cgi file path to src like I did with buttons.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/pEo39xh : current progress

Comment: We need to see the code that is failing and exact text of any error messages. Copy/paste  code/errrMsgs into  your question and use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu to get correct formatting like `code/data/output/errMsgs`. Don't expect readers to goto external websites to underrstand your problem. Do you know about `myProgram > /path/to/my/index.html` ? (`>` redirects output of a program into the specified file). Good luck.

Comment: Or if you think this is really an Rpi problem, delete here and post (with more details) to [raspberrypi.se]. Good luck.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem of communicating with the webserver.

If you create a cgi-program, you will (in general) call it with

```
http://webserver.domain/cgi-bin/scriptname.sh
```

The script then has to be placed in the right directory (often but not always `/var/www/cgi-bin`) and the webserver needs to be instructed to use CGI. Your script then needs to output valid HTML. Note that the script is executed under the user that runs the `httpd`, which is not `root`.

If you want to continue using `index.html`, you could overwrite that file regularly using `cron`. Beware that, if someone fetches the page in the browser when you are updating, it may result in an incomplete page.